# PHP setcookie not working

Tags: php, setcookie

Looks like it should be working:

```
if ($_POST['stayloggedin'] == 'stayloggedin') {

    setcookie("user", $_POST['mail'], time()+7*24*60*60, '/', 'subdomain.example.com', false, true);
    setcookie("hash", md5(sha1(md5($_POST['pw']))), time()+7*24*60*60, '/', 'subdomain.example.com', false, true);

}

header("Location: /"); 
exit();
```

I have put ob_start() on top of the code, so that shouldn't be the point.

Comment: What is not working? Are you sure it's the cookie call that fails, and not the condition? What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: Did you check the HTTP response header?

Comment: check if the code enters the condition

Comment: What you are doing with the hash there is a bad idea.

Comment: The condition works, because when I enter exit() instead of setcookie() it exits. And no cookie is being set.

Comment: What domain are you on, subdomain.example.com?

Comment: If you are checking it in main domain instead of subdomain it will not be accessible there

Comment: The domain is also good, I am working on a subdomain and I just changed it to subdomain.example.com to publish it here because I don't want the website to be visible to everyone yet.

Comment: What if you remove the domain entirely?

Comment: You've put `ob_start()` at the top… but did you put `ob_end_flush()` after setting cookies and headers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

make sure your php.ini file allows cookies..  Also, you should NEVER store sensitive data in a cookie or a session variable.

Suggestion:
store a unique id instead, then query the database for details like usernames and passwords.  You are just asking to get hacked doing it the way you are doing it.

Not to be negative, just a helpful preventative tip.

Comment: Also make sure to store a randomly generated authentication key in a cookie. If you just store a user id, then any user can log in as any other user by editing the cookie. You will need to require that cookies contain both a user ID and a random key which the database is checked for.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you aren't sending any output to the browser before the `setcookie()` function is called. `ob_start()` should stop the "output before `setcookie()`" error, but it might not be implemented correctly.

Comment: I was sending output before setcookie in my bug so this suggestion was a helpful hint. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

mike is right. You are both leaving the page and killing the PHP execution before you even ouput anything. `ob_start()` is in fact the problem: it opens the output buffer (instead of actually sending the data). If you want something to be sent, you have either to flush the buffer (with `ob_end_flush()`) or to wait for the normal end of the PHP script. So in your case, the cookies are not sent at all.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at that code snippet I'd say the problem is that the cookie is never sent to the user's browser. Cookies are stored clientside, not serverside; you're creating two new ones but then immediately calling exit() which kills the PHP script before any response is dispatched from the server to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setcookie("user", $_POST['mail'], time()+7*24*60*60, '/', '.example.com');
setcookie("hash", md5(sha1(md5($_POST['pw']))), time()+7*24*60*60, '/', '.example.com');
```